# Encrypting string with PHP openssl_encrypt

Tags: php, encryption

I'm completely new to encryption and best practices, but doing my best to understand the nuances. I've finally cobbled together the following solution which "works" but I'd appreciate feedback as to whether this is the correct way to be handling encryption/decryption or not. I'm using PHP 7.

```
<?php

$text_to_encrypt = 'My super secret information.';

function random_string($length = 16, $alphabet = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') {
    if ($length < 1) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Length must be a positive integer');
    }
    $string = '';
    $alphamax = strlen($alphabet) - 1;
    if ($alphamax < 1) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid alphabet');
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $string .= $alphabet[random_int(0, $alphamax)];
    }
    return $string;
}

$key = random_string(16);
$iv = random_string(16);

// To encrypt
$encrypted_message = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($text_to_encrypt, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));

// To decrypt
$decrypted_message = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted_message), 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

// Result
var_dump('<b>Text to be encrypted:</b> ' . $text_to_encrypt);
var_dump('<b>Key:</b> ' . $key);
var_dump('<b>Initialization vector:</b> ' . $iv);
var_dump('<b>Encrypted message:</b> ' . $encrypted_message);
var_dump('<b>Decrypted message:</b> ' . $decrypted_message);
```

Constructive feedback would be appreciated so that I and others can learn from what we're reading and doing.

(Giving credit where credit is due)

Random string generation: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php

Implemention of openssl_encrypt: http://thefsb.tumblr.com/post/110749271235/using-opensslendecrypt-in-php-instead-of

Thank you kindly!

Comment: If you're using PHP 7, why not use `random_bytes()`? Seems to me you're trying to reinvent the wheel with that function of yours.

Comment: @Xorifelse - agreed that it's recreating the wheel, but it allows me to limit the alphabet used. For instance, when using random_bytes I'm getting characters such as "¡Nø”P§œpÿ:Â©F". Is it more secure to use this expanded alphabet?

Comment: @RyanVincent - are you referring to the $iv as the salt? I intended to store that value in the database to use for later decryption. Would this accomplish the same thing that you're referring to? As far as I understand, the iv/salt is useless without the key so there's no harm in storing it in plain text.

Comment: @RyanVincent - makes perfect sense and that might be a cleaner way to handle things. See the other comment about using random_bytes. It creates a string without a predictable length, character count. In this fashion, wouldn't it be difficult to store the salt/iv and encrypted string together and then later separate the two again? I suppose I could use a delimiter but in my mind that creates another potential point of failure. Eager to get your input!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129692/discussion-between-jeff-walden-and-ryan-vincent).